# Interface inheritance and the new keyword

Tags: c#, interface

I want:

```
public interface IBase
{
    MyObject Property1 { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseSub<T> : IBase
{
    new T Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IBaseSub<YourObject>
{
    public YourObject Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

But this doesn't compile. It gives the error:

```
//This class must implement the interface member IBase.Property1
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? I thought it should work..

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IBaseSub<T>` *requires* `IBase`. I say "requires" because it more accurately reflects the practical implications than to say it "inherits" `IBase`, which implies overriding and other things that simply don't happen with interfaces. A class which implements `IBaseSub<T>` can actually be said to implement both, like so:

```
public class MyClass : IBase, IBaseSub<YourObject>
```

Going back to what I said about inheritance - there is no such thing with interfaces, which means just because both interfaces have a property with the same name, the derived one isn't overriding or hiding the base one. It means that your class must now **literally implement two properties with the same name** to fulfill both contracts. You can do this with [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx):

```
public class MyClass : IBase, IBaseSub<YourObject>
{
    public YourObject Property1 { get; set; }
    MyObject IBase.Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. It makes sense with the way both Rex M and Jon explained it. Cheers!

Comment: @user654495 great! If an answer solves your problem, please indicate it to the community by clicking the large check-mark to the left of the answer, underneath the voting buttons.

Comment: It has been a while.. but I've marked it as the answer now. Sorry =/

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the properties from both `IBase` and `IBaseSub<YourObject>`, since the latter expands on the former.

Using `new` in `IBaseSub<T>` does not let you "off the hook" regarding the necessity to have a `MyObject Property1 { get; set; }`. It simply allows you to declare *another* property named `Property1` that implementors of `IBaseSub<T>` must have.

Since you cannot have two properties with the same name in `MyClass`, you will be forced to implement at least one of them explicitly:

```
public class MyClass : IBaseSub<YourObject>
{
    MyObject IBase.Property1 { get; set; }
    public YourObject Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is new allowed? What does it mean for an interface?

Comment: @Ritch: It's allowed because the standard says so :) and it allows the  "derived" interface to define members with the same name as those in the interfaces it "derives" from.

Comment: Oh, I guess I could see the use for that. I mean, its a stretch, but I can see it.

Comment: @Ritch Melton: A major use for that is to allow a read-only interface to be extended by a read-write interface.  For whatever reason, .net won't allow a read-only property to be usefully extended merely by defining a set method; one must define separate read-only and read-write properties.