# Ambiguous call to overloaded function with overridden property

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have two base interfaces

```
interface IHasId
{
    int Id {get;} // readonly 
}

interface IEntity : IHasId
{
    new int Id {get; set;} // must be able to assign Ids
}
```

There are then several entities that implement IEntity.

```
interface IThing : IEntity
{
   // thing specific stuff
}
```

These entities are consumed in both C# and C++/Cli. This was all fine until I moved to VS2015.

Now, when I try to access Id in C++

```
void SomeFunction(IThing^ thing)
{ 
    DoSomething(thing->Id);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2668: 'IHasId::Id::get': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>  file.cpp(52): note: could be 'int IHasId::Id::get(void)'
1>  file.cpp(52): note: or       'int IEntity::Id::get(void)'
```

I can workaround this by changing the code to

```
void SomeFunction(IThing^ thing)
{ 
    IHasId x = thing;
    DoSomething(x->Id);
}
```

but that's a massive task to convert all the existing code. This worked fine in 2010. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: No, this works in VS2015 just like it always did.  Your snippets are bogus, they can never demonstrate the problem since the interfaces are not public.  Post **real** code.

Comment: I reproduced the problem in a simple project below. The snippets demonstrate the problem, and the **real** code is part of a project that is over 1 million LOC.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy this code into a very simple project and confirm it's still not working? In your example that's broken you're not touching IEntity so that makes me think there is other code in your project that ties those interfaces together somehow. What you're showing doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Opps, yeah, IThing should have inherited from IEntity. Was trying to reduce the problem to it's simplest form. Have repro'd the problem here. 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67065/AmbiguousCallTest.zip

Looking at it now I think it might have something to do with the framework version.

Comment: you need to uncomment the line in cpplib.cpp to see the error

Comment: Also if you change the platform toolset from 2015 to 2010 the error goes away

Comment: When I try to run your code in csharp and make a class that implements IThing it says I have to implement the Id field from IEntity and IHasId. Using new does not appear to override the field from the inherited interface.I'm not an expert on c-sharp internals so someone with more mojo will have to explain why this is.

Comment: You may also refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400129/interface-inheritance-and-the-new-keyword according to those guys the new operator does not override the field in an inherited interface. It means both have to be implemented. If you are implementing both in your real project then you need to qualify which Id field you're wanting to consume in the c++ project.

Comment: That post is different because the two properties have different return types.

   `public class Thing : IThing
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }`

is completely legal C#